# slow select query mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 8 million of records which has 10 columns and one of the column is 'text' type while other are mainly timestamps or varchar(10). I have all the necessary index created . Table size ~10GB while index ~4GB.  While running a point query my select are performing well but when i select 50% of the rows it takes ages to complete ~30mins . I am not selecting text column . Query plan says atleast one index used.

Any reason why table is not performing ? is it due to text column which stores a blob(generally ~32KB)

Comment: *I have all the necessary index created* Show DDL, including indices. *Query plan says atleast one index used.* Show query and its plan.

Comment: Perhaps it's what you are doing with the 50% of the rows that matters. Are you showing them on the screen? Is it in GUI? Remember that memory needs to be allocated and corresponding structures populated with those rows, perhaps with some data formatting performed along the way. Your query itself might well be fast enough, but consuming that amount of data might be the issue. Still, as @Akina pointed out, you need to add more details for that to be determined.

Comment: 8M records, 10 non-string type fields, 640Mb max. I think the issue is not (only) memory one... more likely the query falls into fullscan + materializing + far LIMIT start issue.

Comment: We've got some really good people around here, but none of us are psychic. 

Show us the Table structure(s). 

Show us the Query. 

Show us the Execution Plan for the query.